# Is there any way to use Anchor tag in json. i am trying and getting same tag in text format. i m rendering in react

Tags: json

I m totally new to programming and trying to use anchor tag in json but I am getting the same tag but in text format.

Max Mustermann moved AIM3D GmbH XYZ UG and ABC GmbH to Validation."

Comment: Max Mustermann moved <a href=''>AIM3D GmbH</a> XYZ UG and ABC GmbH

Comment: thats wat i m getting